# Url rewrite .htaccess with two conditions - Issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying "to convert" the URLs of my site (php + MySQL) in something smarter via htaccess.

I have two page types:

```
www.mysite.com/?s=portfolio
www.mysite.com/?s=scheda&id=1&slug=my-title
```

"to convert" into

```
www.mysite.com/portfolio.html
www.mysite.com/1_my-title.html
```

This is my actual .htaccess and the problem is that **rules work separately** but not together (the second one doesn't work).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

What I am wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I made a mistake. This is my actual .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^_]+)_([^_]+)\.html$ /?s=scheda&id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

Because the second rule is also included in the first